After MongoSocketReadTimeoutException @Scheduled threads got ruined
From logs it visible that every scheduled job takes it's own thread. I set pool size to 10 of them and it was working fine until MongoDB exception. Since we have three clusters all of them time outed and after that Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description (to all three clusters)
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-1]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-1]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-6]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-6]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-6]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-6]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-8]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-8]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-4]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-4]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-7]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-7]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-8]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-8]
INFO 6 --- [  scheduling-10]
INFO 6 --- [  scheduling-10]
INFO 6 --- [  scheduling-10]
INFO 6 --- [  scheduling-10]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-4]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-4]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-3]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-3]
INFO 6 --- [  scheduling-10]
INFO 6 --- [  scheduling-10]
INFO 6 --- [  scheduling-10]
INFO 6 --- [  scheduling-10]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-6]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-6]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-5]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-5]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-2]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-2]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-2]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-2]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-7]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-7]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-8]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-8]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [XXX] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server XXX

After that logs like this. From that point all jobs started running on the same thread once or multiple times then thread changes it goes in this way. Also one of scheduled joba completely stopped running.
INFO 6 --- [XXX] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-9]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-4]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-4]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-4]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-4]
INFO 6 --- [   scheduling-4]

